# Arveson Characterization of Toepltiz Operators

Tags: operator-theory

from book
*A Short Course on Spectral Theory , William Arveson*

Theorem  4.2.4 say

> Let $A$ be a bounded operator on $H^{2}$ satisfying $S^{*}AS=A$. There is a unique function $\phi\in L^{\infty}$ such that $A=T_{\phi}$, and one has $||A||=||\phi||_{\infty}$

I'm stuck in the end, he say

> uniqueness of $\phi$ follows that $||T_{\phi}||=||\phi||_{\infty}$

i don't know how deduce this using what was seen earlier in this book.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

He could have written it slightly better.

What the line means is that, since $\|Tg\|=\|g\|_\infty$ for **any** $g\in L^\infty$, if $T_\phi=T_\psi$ then for any $f\in L^2$ 
$$
0=T_\phi f-T_\psi f=P_+\phi f-P_+\psi f=P_+(\phi-\psi)f=T_{\phi-\psi}f.
$$
So $T_{\phi-\psi}=0$, and then 
$$
0=\|T_{\phi-\psi}\|=\|\phi-\psi\|_\infty.
$$
implying that $\psi=\phi$ in $L^\infty$.

Comment: thanks for answer. but why $||T_{g}||=||g||_{\infty}$ for any $g\in L^{\infty}$. arveson don't show map $g\rightarrow T_{g}$ is isometric.  i could use murphy's book for show this map isometric

Comment: You can apply the arguments in the proof of Theorem 4.2.4 to $A=T_g$ and $\bar A=M_g$.

Comment: another question, when he said "it follows from 4.7 that we can use Riesz lemma". for this he use $$\psi : {\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n\geq 1}}{M_n}}\times {\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n\geq 1}}{M_n}}$$, $$\psi( \xi ,\eta)=\displaystyle{\lim_{ n \to \infty   }}{\langle A_{n} \xi   , \eta   \rangle}$$, and after extend $$\widetilde{\psi}$$ to $$\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{T})\times\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{T})$$ for be uniformly continuous; and fter yes use riesz lemma. is good my think? thanks

Comment: i still without understood why arveson afirm $$\|T_{\phi - \psi}\|=\|\phi - \psi\|_{\infty}$$....

Comment: That's a vague question. Arveson shows that $\tilde A=M_\phi$, that $P_+\tilde A=A$, and that $\|\tilde A\|=\|A\|$. So start with $A=T_\phi$, and you have $$\|T_\phi\|=\|A\|=\|\tilde A\|=\|\phi\|_\infty.$$ That's what Arveson does in 4.2.4.

Comment: but if i start probe uniqueness, i said if $$T_{\phi-\psi}=0$$ so, $$0=\|T_{\phi-\psi}\|\leq\|\phi-\psi\|_{\infty}$$, he don't probe the reverse equal $$\|T_{\phi-\psi}\|\geq\|\phi-\psi\|_{\infty}$$. and if i start the proof with $$T_{\phi-\psi}$$ and repet the proces, i get exist $$\varphi$$ that $$P_{+}(\varphi)=P_{+}({\phi-\psi})$$. why $$P_{-}(\varphi)=P_{-}({\phi-\psi})$$. this is my confusion....

Comment: Yes he does. As I said, he proves that $\|A\|=\|\tilde A\|$. And $\tilde A$ is $M_\phi$, and it is a basic fact that $\|M_\phi\|=\|\phi\|_\infty$.